# Privoxy - Block access to local network

Tags: proxy, config, privoxy

I have setup a little privoxy server on my pi and i try now to block all ips in the local nerwork, but it does not work.

My attempt was this:

```
deny-access 128.0.0.1/2 192.168.0.0/16
```

It should stop all users of privoxy to access my local network.

Also as a side question, is there a way to add a username and password for verification?